# Read json list in java

Tags: java, java-8, apache-kafka-streams

Previously I was reading json data in the following format:

**JSON**

```
{
    "CreationTime":"2018-01-12T12:32:31",
    "Id":"08f81fd7-21f1-48ba-a991-08d559b88cc5",
    "Operation":"AddedToGroup",
    "RecordType":14,
    "UserType":0,
    "Version":1,
    "Workload":"OneDrive",
    "ClientIP":"115.186.129.229",
    "UserId":"omaji7@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com",
    "EventSource":"SharePoint",
    "ItemType":"Web"
}
```

I am reading this json data from a kafka topic and doing some stream processing on it and passing it onto another topic. In processing I have created two json objects, `send` and `received`.

**Using this code:**

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

KStream<String, String> source_o365_user_activity = builder.stream("o365_user_activity");

        source_o365_user_activity.flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<String, Iterable<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Iterable<String> apply(String value) {
                System.out.println("========> o365_user_activity_by_date Log:     " + value);
                ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
                try {
                    JSONObject send = new JSONObject();
                    JSONObject received = new JSONObject(value);

                    send.put("current_date", getCurrentDate().toString()); // UTC TIME
                    send.put("activity_time", received.get("CreationTime")); // CONSTANTS FINAL STATIC(Topic Names, Cassandra keys)
                    send.put("user_id", received.get("UserId"));
                    send.put("operation_type", received.get("Operation"));
                    send.put("app_name", received.get("Workload"));
                    keywords.add(send.toString());
                    // apply regex to value and for each match add it to keywords

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    System.err.println("Unable to convert to json");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return keywords;
            }
        }).to("o365_user_activity_by_date");
```

This was fairly simple. Now I have a json data with lists in them.

**JSON**

```
{
  "CreationTime":"2017-12-27T07:47:46",
  "Id":"10ee505b-90a4-4ac1-b96f-a6dbca939694",
  "Operation":"Add member to role.",
  "OrganizationId":"2f88f444-62da-4aae-b8af-8331a6915801",
  "RecordType":8,
  "ResultStatus":"success",
  "UserKey":"10030000A656FE5B@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com",
  "UserType":0,
  "Version":1,
  "Workload":"AzureActiveDirectory",
  "ObjectId":"mustafa@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com",
  "UserId":"omaji7@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com",
  "AzureActiveDirectoryEventType":1,
  "ExtendedProperties":[
     {
        "Name":"Role.ObjectID",
        "Value":"b0f54661-2d74-4c50-afa3-1ec803f12efe"
     },
     {
        "Name":"Role.DisplayName",
        "Value":"Billing Administrator"
     },
     {
        "Name":"Role.TemplateId",
        "Value":"b0f54661-2d74-4c50-afa3-1ec803f12efe"
     },
     {
        "Name":"Role.WellKnownObjectName",
        "Value":"BillingAdmins"
     }
  ],
  "Actor":[
     {
        "ID":"omaji7@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com",
        "Type":5
     },
     {
        "ID":"10030000A656FE5B",
        "Type":3
     },
     {
        "ID":"User_d03ca514-adfa-4585-a8bd-7182a9a086c7",
        "Type":2
     }
  ],
  "ActorContextId":"2f88f444-62da-4aae-b8af-8331a6915801",
  "InterSystemsId":"6d402a5b-c5de-4d9f-a805-9371c109e55f",
  "IntraSystemId":"a5568d01-f100-497a-b88b-c9731ff31248",
  "Target":[
     {
        "ID":"User_8f77c311-3ea0-4146-9f7d-db21bd052d3d",
        "Type":2
     },
     {
        "ID":"mustafa@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com",
        "Type":5
     },
     {
        "ID":"1003BFFDA67CCA03",
        "Type":3
     }
  ],
  "TargetContextId":"2f88f444-62da-4aae-b8af-8331a6915801"
}
```

How can I go about doing the same thing in my Stream processing?
I want to be able to read JSON data against some keys (including the list data keys).

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert JSON to Object and then filter against using the field in Object?

Comment: I am converting each string (i.e. JSON data) to a JSON object. I want to know if a list against a key in JSON data would simply map or not?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do like this?

```
send.put("target_0_id", received.get("Target").getJSONObject(0).get("ID"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gson library and can convert the json to object and using getter and setter you can build your desired output JSON. You can also parse the input JSON to fetch the JSONArray details. Following is the code how you can do it using POJO.

Input class:

```
public class Input {


    private String UserType;

    private String TargetContextId;

    private String RecordType;

    private String Operation;

    private String Workload;

    private String UserId;

    private String OrganizationId;

    private String InterSystemsId;

    private ExtendedProperties[] ExtendedProperties;

    private String ActorContextId;

    private String CreationTime;

    private String IntraSystemId;

    private Target[] Target;

    private Actor[] Actor;

    private String Id;

    private String Version;

    private String ResultStatus;

    private String ObjectId;

    private String AzureActiveDirectoryEventType;

    private String UserKey;

    public String getUserType ()
    {
        return UserType;
    }

    public void setUserType (String UserType)
    {
        this.UserType = UserType;
    }

    public String getTargetContextId ()
    {
        return TargetContextId;
    }

    public void setTargetContextId (String TargetContextId)
    {
        this.TargetContextId = TargetContextId;
    }

    public String getRecordType ()
    {
        return RecordType;
    }

    public void setRecordType (String RecordType)
    {
        this.RecordType = RecordType;
    }

    public String getOperation ()
    {
        return Operation;
    }

    public void setOperation (String Operation)
    {
        this.Operation = Operation;
    }

    public String getWorkload ()
    {
        return Workload;
    }

    public void setWorkload (String Workload)
    {
        this.Workload = Workload;
    }

    public String getUserId ()
    {
        return UserId;
    }

    public void setUserId (String UserId)
    {
        this.UserId = UserId;
    }

    public String getOrganizationId ()
    {
        return OrganizationId;
    }

    public void setOrganizationId (String OrganizationId)
    {
        this.OrganizationId = OrganizationId;
    }

    public String getInterSystemsId ()
    {
        return InterSystemsId;
    }

    public void setInterSystemsId (String InterSystemsId)
    {
        this.InterSystemsId = InterSystemsId;
    }

    public ExtendedProperties[] getExtendedProperties ()
    {
        return ExtendedProperties;
    }

    public void setExtendedProperties (ExtendedProperties[] ExtendedProperties)
    {
        this.ExtendedProperties = ExtendedProperties;
    }

    public String getActorContextId ()
    {
        return ActorContextId;
    }

    public void setActorContextId (String ActorContextId)
    {
        this.ActorContextId = ActorContextId;
    }

    public String getCreationTime ()
    {
        return CreationTime;
    }

    public void setCreationTime (String CreationTime)
    {
        this.CreationTime = CreationTime;
    }

    public String getIntraSystemId ()
    {
        return IntraSystemId;
    }

    public void setIntraSystemId (String IntraSystemId)
    {
        this.IntraSystemId = IntraSystemId;
    }

    public Target[] getTarget ()
    {
        return Target;
    }

    public void setTarget (Target[] Target)
    {
        this.Target = Target;
    }

    public Actor[] getActor ()
    {
        return Actor;
    }

    public void setActor (Actor[] Actor)
    {
        this.Actor = Actor;
    }

    public String getId ()
    {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId (String Id)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public String getVersion ()
    {
        return Version;
    }

    public void setVersion (String Version)
    {
        this.Version = Version;
    }

    public String getResultStatus ()
    {
        return ResultStatus;
    }

    public void setResultStatus (String ResultStatus)
    {
        this.ResultStatus = ResultStatus;
    }

    public String getObjectId ()
    {
        return ObjectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId (String ObjectId)
    {
        this.ObjectId = ObjectId;
    }

    public String getAzureActiveDirectoryEventType ()
    {
        return AzureActiveDirectoryEventType;
    }

    public void setAzureActiveDirectoryEventType (String AzureActiveDirectoryEventType)
    {
        this.AzureActiveDirectoryEventType = AzureActiveDirectoryEventType;
    }

    public String getUserKey ()
    {
        return UserKey;
    }

    public void setUserKey (String UserKey)
    {
        this.UserKey = UserKey;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [UserType = "+UserType+", TargetContextId = "+TargetContextId+", RecordType = "+RecordType+", Operation = "+Operation+", Workload = "+Workload+", UserId = "+UserId+", OrganizationId = "+OrganizationId+", InterSystemsId = "+InterSystemsId+", ExtendedProperties = "+ExtendedProperties+", ActorContextId = "+ActorContextId+", CreationTime = "+CreationTime+", IntraSystemId = "+IntraSystemId+", Target = "+Target+", Actor = "+Actor+", Id = "+Id+", Version = "+Version+", ResultStatus = "+ResultStatus+", ObjectId = "+ObjectId+", AzureActiveDirectoryEventType = "+AzureActiveDirectoryEventType+", UserKey = "+UserKey+"]";
    }}
```

Target class:

```
public class Target {
private String Type;

private String ID;

public String getType() {
    return Type;
}

public void setType(String Type) {
    this.Type = Type;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ClassPojo [Type = " + Type + ", ID = " + ID + "]";
}}
```

Actor class :

```
public class Actor {
private String Type;

private String ID;

public String getType() {
    return Type;
}

public void setType(String Type) {
    this.Type = Type;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ClassPojo [Type = " + Type + ", ID = " + ID + "]";
}}
```

ExtendedProperties class :

```
public class ExtendedProperties {
private String Name;

private String Value;

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
}

public String getValue() {
    return Value;
}

public void setValue(String Value) {
    this.Value = Value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ClassPojo [Name = " + Name + ", Value = " + Value + "]";
}}
```

Main class :

```
public class Stack {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    doIt();
}

private static void doIt() {
    String received = "{\"CreationTime\":\"2017-12-27T07:47:46\",\"Id\":\"10ee505b-90a4-4ac1-b96f-a6dbca939694\",\"Operation\":\"Add member to role.\",\"OrganizationId\":\"2f88f444-62da-4aae-b8af-8331a6915801\",\"RecordType\":8,\"ResultStatus\":\"success\",\"UserKey\":\"10030000A656FE5B@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com\",\"UserType\":0,\"Version\":1,\"Workload\":\"AzureActiveDirectory\",\"ObjectId\":\"mustafa@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com\",\"UserId\":\"omaji7@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com\",\"AzureActiveDirectoryEventType\":1,\"ExtendedProperties\":[{\"Name\":\"Role.ObjectID\",\"Value\":\"b0f54661-2d74-4c50-afa3-1ec803f12efe\"},{\"Name\":\"Role.DisplayName\",\"Value\":\"Billing Administrator\"},{\"Name\":\"Role.TemplateId\",\"Value\":\"b0f54661-2d74-4c50-afa3-1ec803f12efe\"},{\"Name\":\"Role.WellKnownObjectName\",\"Value\":\"BillingAdmins\"}],\"Actor\":[{\"ID\":\"omaji7@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com\",\"Type\":5},{\"ID\":\"10030000A656FE5B\",\"Type\":3},{\"ID\":\"User_d03ca514-adfa-4585-a8bd-7182a9a086c7\",\"Type\":2}],\"ActorContextId\":\"2f88f444-62da-4aae-b8af-8331a6915801\",\"InterSystemsId\":\"6d402a5b-c5de-4d9f-a805-9371c109e55f\",\"IntraSystemId\":\"a5568d01-f100-497a-b88b-c9731ff31248\",\"Target\":[{\"ID\":\"User_8f77c311-3ea0-4146-9f7d-db21bd052d3d\",\"Type\":2},{\"ID\":\"mustafa@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com\",\"Type\":5},{\"ID\":\"1003BFFDA67CCA03\",\"Type\":3}],\"TargetContextId\":\"2f88f444-62da-4aae-b8af-8331a6915801\"}";
    JSONObject send = new JSONObject();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Input inputObject = gson.fromJson(received, Input.class);

    // you can add values here and customize the output JSON
    send.put("userId", inputObject.getUserId());
    send.put("Workload", inputObject.getWorkload());

    // read Actor list
    Actor[] arr = inputObject.getActor();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // write your logic here how you want to handle the Actor list
        // values
        System.out.println(arr[i].getID() + " : " + arr[i].getType());
    }

    // read ExtendedProperties list
    ExtendedProperties[] extendedProperties = inputObject.getExtendedProperties();
    for (int j = 0; j < extendedProperties.length; j++) {
        // write your logic here how you want to handle the
        // ExtendedProperties list values
        System.out.println(extendedProperties[j].getName() + " : " + extendedProperties[j].getValue());
    }

    System.out.println("*************");
}}
```

alternate main class without using POJO. Here `org.json` library have been used to parse the input JSON.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    doIt();
}

private static void doIt() {
    String received = "{\"CreationTime\":\"2017-12-27T07:47:46\",\"Id\":\"10ee505b-90a4-4ac1-b96f-a6dbca939694\",\"Operation\":\"Add member to role.\",\"OrganizationId\":\"2f88f444-62da-4aae-b8af-8331a6915801\",\"RecordType\":8,\"ResultStatus\":\"success\",\"UserKey\":\"10030000A656FE5B@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com\",\"UserType\":0,\"Version\":1,\"Workload\":\"AzureActiveDirectory\",\"ObjectId\":\"mustafa@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com\",\"UserId\":\"omaji7@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com\",\"AzureActiveDirectoryEventType\":1,\"ExtendedProperties\":[{\"Name\":\"Role.ObjectID\",\"Value\":\"b0f54661-2d74-4c50-afa3-1ec803f12efe\"},{\"Name\":\"Role.DisplayName\",\"Value\":\"Billing Administrator\"},{\"Name\":\"Role.TemplateId\",\"Value\":\"b0f54661-2d74-4c50-afa3-1ec803f12efe\"},{\"Name\":\"Role.WellKnownObjectName\",\"Value\":\"BillingAdmins\"}],\"Actor\":[{\"ID\":\"omaji7@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com\",\"Type\":5},{\"ID\":\"10030000A656FE5B\",\"Type\":3},{\"ID\":\"User_d03ca514-adfa-4585-a8bd-7182a9a086c7\",\"Type\":2}],\"ActorContextId\":\"2f88f444-62da-4aae-b8af-8331a6915801\",\"InterSystemsId\":\"6d402a5b-c5de-4d9f-a805-9371c109e55f\",\"IntraSystemId\":\"a5568d01-f100-497a-b88b-c9731ff31248\",\"Target\":[{\"ID\":\"User_8f77c311-3ea0-4146-9f7d-db21bd052d3d\",\"Type\":2},{\"ID\":\"mustafa@emumbaa10.onmicrosoft.com\",\"Type\":5},{\"ID\":\"1003BFFDA67CCA03\",\"Type\":3}],\"TargetContextId\":\"2f88f444-62da-4aae-b8af-8331a6915801\"}";
    JSONObject send = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject input = new JSONObject(received);

    // you can add values here and customize the output JSON
    send.put("userId", input.getString("UserId"));
    send.put("Workload", input.getString("Workload"));

    // read Actor list
    JSONArray actorArray = input.getJSONArray("Actor");
    for (int i = 0; i < actorArray.length(); i++) {
        // write your logic here how you want to handle the Actor list
        // values
        System.out.println(
                actorArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ID") + ":" + actorArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("Type"));
    }

    // read ExtendedProperties list
    JSONArray extendedProperties = input.getJSONArray("ExtendedProperties");
    for (int j = 0; j < extendedProperties.length(); j++) {
        // write your logic here how you want to handle the
        // ExtendedProperties list values
        System.out.println(extendedProperties.getJSONObject(j).getString("Name") + " : "
                + extendedProperties.getJSONObject(j).getString("Value"));
    }

    System.out.println("*************");
}}
```